# Parallel ForEach using a ConcurrentBag not working as expected

Tags: c#, concurrency, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I have this code that processes items in a list:

```
    static readonly object _Lock = new object();

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name;
        public string ID;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var items = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { Name = "One", ID = "123" },
            new Item { Name = "Two", ID = "234" },
            new Item { Name = "Three", ID = "123" }
        };

        var itemsProcess = new ConcurrentBag<Item>();
        Parallel.ForEach(items, (item) =>
        {
            Item itemProcess = null;
            // lock (_Lock)
            {
                itemProcess = itemsProcess.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == item.ID);
            }
            if (itemProcess != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Item [{item.Name}] was already processed as [{itemProcess.Name}]");
            }
            else
            {
                itemsProcess.Add(item);
                Console.WriteLine($"Processing item [{item.Name}]");
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // do some work...
            }
        });

        Console.ReadKey();
      }
```

I am basically using the `ConcurrentBag` to check for the existence of an object based on several conditions.
I am **expecting** to always get an output like (order may vary):

```
Processing item [One]
Item [Three] was already processed as [One]
Processing item [Two]
```

But I **sometimes** get an output, which suggests my code is not thread safe:

```
Processing item [Three]
Processing item [One]
Processing item [Two]
```

So my assumption that `itemsProcess.FirstOrDefault()` will block was wrong.
Using the `lock` does not change anything. obviously, something is wrong here, and I really can't understand why?

I know I can "solve" this in other ways (one is to prepare the list before entering `Parallel.ForEach()`), but I really like to know **why** is this behavior?

Comment: Concurrentbag are already thread safe so lock does not change anything here. And also Parallel foreach loop starts 3 parallel threads so every time itemProcess  will be null and hence else part will execute. If I changed ConcurrentBag to List and use lock then it works for me because now lock will be considered for normal list.

Comment: Your example contains two `Item` objects with the same `ID`. Is this intentional?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, `ID` can be duplicated and only the first item with a given `ID` needs to be processed.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay oh, I see. Probably this clarification should be part of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have 2 independent operations within your parallel loop: `FirstOrDefault` and `Add`.

`ConcurrentBag` cannot ensure thread-safety between these 2 operations.

An alternative would be `ConcurrentDictionary`, which has a `GetOrAdd` method that will only add an item when the key is not present:

```
var itemsProcess = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Item>();
Parallel.ForEach(items, item =>
{
    // Returns existing item with same ID or adds this item
    var itemProcess = itemsProcess.GetOrAdd(item.Id, item);
    if (!object.ReferenceEquals(item, itemProcess))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Item [{item.Name}] was already processed as [{itemProcess.Name}]");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Processing item [{item.Name}]");
        // do some work...
    }
});
```

If you then need the processed Items as an `ICollection`, they can be accessed via `itemsProcess.Values`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why, is because there is still a *data race*... 2 threads can still read and add to the `ConcurrentBag` in a *non-thread safe* manner. Using any of the *concurrent collections* only means you have a structure which is *self-consistent*, but it doesn't protect you from writing other *non-thread safe* code

You had the right idea with a `lock`

```
var itemsProcess = new Dictionary<string, Item>();
Parallel.ForEach(items, (item) =>
{

   lock (_Lock)
   {
      if (itemsProcess.TryGetValue(item.ID, out var val))
      {
         Console.WriteLine($"Item [{item.Name}] was already processed as [{val.Name}]");
         return;
      }

      itemsProcess.TryAdd(item.ID, item);
   }

   Console.WriteLine($"Processing item [{item.Name}]");
   Thread.Sleep(1000); // do some work...

});
```

<sub>***Note** : You could also filter list for duplicates before you process it in parallel, this saves needing a lock or collection at all*</sub>

Comment: I would go with prefiltering the list. What's the point of using a `Parallel.ForEach()` with a `lock()`?

Comment: @TanveerBadar agree totally :) though maybe there is some other logic dependent the current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Without resorting to a lock, you can "abuse" a `ConcurrentDictionary` and avoid all locking here to ensure uniqueness.

Add items to your dictionary by their ID, the data structure will stay consistent and once that's done you can work with the `dictionary.Values` field to get the unique items.

P.S.: I feel like your example is much more involved because no one does a `Distinct()` using `Parallel.ForEach()` which is what your code amounts to.

Finally, to address the reason why this is happening, when it comes to concurrency this is almost always an anti-pattern and doesn't do what the author meant here.

```
if(!collection.Contains(item))
      collection.Add(item);
```

By the time that `Contains()` has executed and returned false another thread could have executed the same, raced ahead and added the same item.

This race condition is why nearly all collection modifying operations come in two flavors: you either have a `collection.TryAdd()` which will try to atomically add an item and return true/false to tell you the outcome or you have things like `GetOrAdd()` and `AddOrUpdate()` which again atomically insert an item and get/update it afterwards.